# How can I get an image too big from a server?

Tags: java, servlets, blackberry, client-server

I'm currenty developing for blackberry and just bumped into this problem as i was trying to download an image from a server. The servlet which the device communicates with is working correctly, as I have made a number of tests for it. But it gives me the

> 413 HTTP error ("Request entity too large").

I figure i will just get the bytes, uhm, portion by portion. How can i accomplish this?

This is the code of the servlet (the `doGet()` method):

```
try {
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("c:\\Users\\dcalderon\\prueba.png");

    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
    PngEncoder pngEncoder = new PngEncoder(image, true);
    output.write(pngEncoder.pngEncode());

} finally {            
    output.close();        
}
```

Thanks. It's worth mentioning that I am developing both the client-side and the server-side.

Comment: Have you tried using a compressed stream? I suggest you specify a `content-encoding` such as `gzip`.

Comment: I really don't have that much experience in HTTP. But I'll look into it and I'll let you know so you can post your comment as an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: can you tell us how big the image is (in bytes)?

Comment: If its too big , you may need to use multipart uploading & downloading.

Comment: @Nate Actually the image is just 51kb. But firebug indicates the size of the request is 2.2 MB (!).

Comment: @Shashank That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I just don't have that much HTTP experience. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware by server side code. You can look on this Link to get an idea how to upload file using multipart to support Big files uploading

it can also work on blackberry , With some modifications needed.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `PNGEncoder` class you're using, but just looking at your servlet code, and the comment you made about the request size (2.2 MB), I'm guessing that part of your problem is that you're **uncompressing** the image, and **then** transmitting it across the network.

I don't think you should have any `PNGEncoder` or `ImageIcon` code in your servlet.  You should just read the `"c:\\Users\\dcalderon\\prueba.png"` file in with a normal `InputStream` as bytes, and then write that to the servlet's output.  I don't think it matters whether that file is a PNG image, a .mp3 file, or any other content.  (although you might need to set the **Content Type** to `image/png`).

So, I would try transmitting the image **compressed** (as a .png just as it's stored on disk).  If that still doesn't work, then go with the suggestion to use *multipart* transmission.